# Function for casting "" to NULL

Tags: php

I have 3 input fields

```
<input type="text" name="first">
<input type="text" name="second">
<input type="text" name="third">
```

and i need a PHP function for backend that will change/cast the input field to NULL if user doesn't type nothing in it.

This is what i have made but it is too complicated:

```
if ($first == ""){
     $first = NULL;
}

if ($second == ""){
     $second = NULL;
}

if ($third == ""){
     $third = NULL;
}
```

So the question is can this be done all in one function and simpler?

Something like:

If any field is an empty string "" then set that field to NULL.

Comment: Maybe `function set_null($test) {
     return !empty($test) ? $test : NULL;
}`?

Comment: What you're asking go's a bit against the nature of PHP. But you could do it with a simple function.

Comment: I'm here to learn...i am open to any suggestions so if you could explain it to me or show....?

Comment: I find it's generally easier to do automation like this when it's an array, that way you can use filtering, sorting, and looping on the input, but it's hard to know if that approach will work since there is no indication of how you are using the variables `$first`, `$second`, and `$third`

Comment: i am just saving them to DB...so if they are empty then i want to save NULL instead of empty string!

Comment: What about just setting the default value in the DB to NULL and not writing the empty fields?

Comment: Well that is the main problem here...if i set default value to NULL...it saves an empty string....i don't know why....but NULL is not the same as empty string

Comment: Well the question should be about that. You're adding more steps to your code this way. If you send an empty string it will write that. Don't include the column/variable when empty, then the default will work...

Comment: I am using Laravel so if you know how can i do that in Laravel please tell me?

Comment: You could use an IF statement in SQL to convert empty strings to NULL, ( `IF(:VAL = '', :VAL, NULL)`) and just leave them as empty strings in PHP.

Comment: Where to put that? I am using Laravel

Comment: Ah, I wouldn't have known that @lewis4u because you didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: I don't know laravel. You should probably re-write the question so the issue you are trying to fix is clear. I wouldn't create a `null` caster for this.

Comment: what would you do then? lets discuss it...

Comment: Use the DB's default `NULL`  as it's designed. Only write the columns that have values. Use the `@` if commenting to people directly, I'm off.

Comment: By default in Laravel on submit it will save all the fields with values. But in my DB this field is a decimal type and MySql doesn't allow to save empty string for decimal type...

Comment: It can be NULL, not empty. `empty` != `NULL`.

Comment: I tried now and i get an error  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first' cannot be null, so i will just save it as zero instead 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
function isEmpty($dato){ 
    if(empty($dato)){
        $dato=NULL;
    }
    return $dato;
}
```

Comment: redefining an existing function?

Comment: i can change the name of the function, that is not the problem

Comment: I am testing it now so if it works i will accept this as an answer.

Comment: I can't save it as NULL but i can save it as 0 as ZERO

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP7 you can try something like:

```
function checkIsEmpty(string &...$strings) {
    foreach ($strings as &$string) {
        if (empty($string)) {
            $string = NULL;
        }
    }
}


checkIsEmpty($a, $b, $c);
```

This will replace all empty strings with NULL.

Alternatively, using PHP5:

```
function checkIsEmpty($string) {
    return (empty($string) ? NULL : $string);
}
```

I'm posting this only because redefining `is_null()` is not the best idea, even not taking the 3 extra lines into account. Anything longer than 1 liner is a waste of space for such a simple function.

Comment: While the accepted solution works (if the function name is changed), this one honestly deserves to be the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no way for the accepted solution to work. First of all, we can't redefine `is_null()`. Secondly, he is missing the dollar sign in `dato=NULL;`

Comment: I didn't even notice the missing dollar sign lol, I meant it works if the function is renamed, though. It's too messy for what it's doing.

Comment: Personally I'll not even bother writing a function for this as it is always 1 line - calling the function or check & replace in place, but anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're dealing with form input so maybe something like this is what you want:

```
$_POST = array_map($_POST, function($v) { return $v == '' ? NULL : $v;})
```

Comment: Yup, this would be the best one if 100% of the fields can be null in the database.